# Is Flash installed on Mac OS by default?

Tags: flash, macos, appstore-approval

I'm an author of a small Windows application written mainly in Action Script (Flash).
With the opening of Apple Mac App Store we have decided to port it to Mac OS.
The Mac version of our app is hosted inside WebView, the main-menu is Mac native.

Unfortunately, the application has been rejected by Apple reviewers.
This is the argument.

> 2.24 Apps that use deprecated or optionally installed technologies
>   (e.g., Java, Rosetta) will be rejected

I don't want to give up.
So I'm wondering if Flash is "optionally installed technology" on Mac OS?
As far as I remember, it has been already installed on my Mac Book.

And, I'm sorry, a small question in advance.
I have managed to find one application using Flash in Mac App Store.
But have you seen any Flash applications there?

Comment: Don't tell to the Apple reviewers that you found an app using Flash in the Mac App Store. They'll remove it, instead of allowing yours in :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash is no longer bundled: http://daringfireball.net/2010/10/apple_no_longer_bundling_flash_with_mac_os_x